# How to run eslint in create react app

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

Help to run eslint in create react app.

I created react app with [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application)

Then I installed

```
babel-eslint

standard

snazzy
```

and then I added to script in package.json next line

```
"lint": "standart --verbose | snazzy"
```

and now I tried to run eslint with command: `npm run lint`

but I have an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token =  null`

My full package.json is below

```js
{
  "name": "square_app_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "standart --verbose | snazzy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "standard": "^10.0.2"
  }
}
```

Please help to understand how to fix it or how to correct run eslint in my situation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your spelling is off in your package.json script. It should be:

```
"lint": "standard --verbose | snazzy"
```

You also need to configure standard to use babel-eslint. Make sure to add this to your package.json.

```
{
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
}
```

Comment: the same result, did not help

Comment: You also need to install snazzy

Comment: Ah, there is one more thing to add to your package.json. It needs this:

{
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
}

Comment: awesome, you saved my time for sleep)

Comment: maybe you know quickly  way how to fix code with eslint in my situation? 
I found some solution with --fix, but do not know how to use it in correct way

Comment: try "standard --fix". In the docs it says this will format everything for you. Another thing to try is using a standard plugin in your text editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149172/discussion-between-ej-mason-and-a-kozubenko).

Answer (score 9):

I added this following script to scripts in package.json:

```
"lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
```

Answer (score 4):

To run EsLint inside `src` folder:

```
./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/eslint src
```

Comment: Is there a way to run `eslint` *not* from node_modules? I have a CRA project where it can be run like this but cannot figure out how it was set up this way.

Comment: @lazy.lizard Just use the path to your eslint binary followed by `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent React scripts (version 5 at least, it appears) install `eslint` directly, so you can add the following line to the `"scripts"` section of `package.json`:

```
"lint": "eslint .",
```

(Omitting the dot causes eslint not to do anything.)

Comment: That does not lint anything, you need to define what to run on, like tal952 does